# Deploying MVC Area as a self standing web site

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have an MVC Application with multiple Areas.  They share a lot of common code and components, so I do not want to break them up into separate Projects.  But I would like to deploy them to separate web sites.

The normal routing is:

```
www.mysharedsite.com/Area1
www.mysharedsite.com/Area2
...
```

But I would like to deploy them as:

```
www.area1site.com/
www.area2site.com/
...
```

I was thinking of putting a field in the web.config and then adding logic in the RouteConfig and the RegisterAreas of each area to change the Routes and turn off Routes to Controllers altogether.  But this seems kludgy.

Is there a clean way of doing this?

Comment: This has nothing to do with ASP.NET and everything to do with IIS (your web server). You can point `www.area1site.com/` to `www.mysharedsite.com/Area1`

Comment: @Nick, that idea works when you want to point a virtual directory of a site to the root of an ASP.Net application, but my question is the opposite of that.  I can't "point" IIS to Area1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is create and install a custom ActionInvoker which reads the hostname from the request, and based on it, sets the appropriate Area path for you:

```
protected override ActionResult InvokeActionMethod(...)
{
    // Get hostname
    var hostname = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.Host;

    if (hostname == "some value you want")
    {
        controllerContext.RouteData.DataTokens["area"] = "your area here";
    }

    return base.InvokeActionMethod(controllerContext, actionDescriptor, parameters);
}
```

Comment: Thanks David.  I like the idea of reading the hostname of the request, but how does a custom ActionInvoker or ControllerFactory solve the Routing issue?  Is there an example that might shed some light?

Comment: I'll get back to you tomorrow once I've looked at how we did it at work - been a while since I touched that code.

Comment: Edited the answer with a more explicit implementation.

Comment: This worked, pretty neat!  It's amazing how flexible MVC is.  I had to change my Area Routes to remove the "Area1" from the Url, which should be fine as long as Controller names don't conflict with other Controllers in the Project.  I also added piece to check if the hostname isn't what I want to not allow access to the Area.

Answer (score 1):

You could specify a route based on the hostname, mapping it to an area. Based on the URL format in your question:

```
routes.Add("DomainRoute", new DomainRoute( 
    "{area}site.com",     // Domain with parameters 
    "{id}",    // URL with parameters 
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults 
));
```

See this post for the DomainRoute class:

http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2009/05/20/ASPNET-MVC-Domain-Routing.aspx

Comment: DomainRoute look very promising.  I'll try this out.

Comment: Sure, let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: I believe this will probably work, but I accepted David's answer as it worked and was quick to hook up.  I will probably use this Domain Route in the future though.

Answer (score 0):

Why not put the common code in a seperate dll
and link your websites to this dll?

Your solution will be a lot bigger if you add another website that also shares the common code.

Comment: Yes, I considered that.  There are a lot of (maybe not great) reasons that I want them as Areas in the same project such as shared views and the same set of components which would have to be added (and updated) to each project.  I'm also determined to find out if there is a clean solution to my problem without rearranging the structure of my current project.

Comment: I understand you. What are your reason(2) for the Areas?

Comment: I have an Admin section, an API, and two consumer facing web site as Areas.  They share many of the same domain and view models and 3rd party components.  To me, it made sense to make them Areas.